# Gimp snap Help not working

Tags: snap, gimp

I had Gimp installed as a snap. This morning I hit the Help button and was unable to get access to Help documentation, either internally or online. The error message suggested something was "missing" and I needed to install it but I was unable to understand this message, and therefore unable to proceed.
I have removed the snap and installed Gimp via the Software store but am unhappy because, first, I don't understand why this failure occurred, and second the version of Gimp is older than the snap version. 
In my view the snap installation should enable reference to Help without needing supplementary add-ons.
Can anyone advise how I can get the snap version of Gimp to work?

Comment: Indeed, the snap indicates that help should be installed. I do not see a way to install help files accessible by the snap version. This might be another drawback of the snap format.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend installing the gimp flatpak.

https://www.gimp.org/downloads/

For the gimp flatpak...

```
flatpak run org.gimp.GIMP --help
```

Comment: I typed /snap/bin/gimp --help in the terminal and got the response  bash: /snap/bin is a directory.

Comment: I revised my answer. @ Roy G

Comment: I contacted the chaps on the Snapcraft site and they have confirmed that "...with regard to the documentation, (they have) been struggling to get webkit2gtk working or successfully compiling. The webkit renderer is required for viewing the documentation, unfortunately." They asked for some outputs from terminal inputs they provided so I am waiting for more debugging info from them.

Comment: The flatpak has its problems, too... and IMHO much worse than a failing Help (no access to the real /tmp (it has a /tmp, but that's not the same one as for other apps, so no way to exchange temp files...), distinct Python runtime...).

Comment: Thanks but an alternative (flatpacks) is not for me just yet. I want to see what transpires with the snap dialogue.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on 18.04, install a "native" version using Otto's PPA:

https://launchpad.net/~otto-kesselgulasch/+archive/ubuntu/gimp

You'll get regular updates. And you can also use this PPA to install up-to-date versions of the more popular plugins.

Comment: If the issue cannot be solved with the snap version, this would be the best way to use the more recent Gimp version.

Comment: I am on 16.04. I also prefer to use snaps or software through the Ubuntu Software tool.

Comment: A third solution is to use an [appimage](https://github.com/aferrero2707/gimp-appimage/releases/tag/continuous), also with its problems (when I tried it it wouldn't run python plugins/scripts).